# pointer to function that return pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, self-reference

I'm trying to code an kind of `ArrayList` (struct) defined as follow:

```
typedef struct {
    int reservedSize; // reserved size
    int size; // Size of list
    void ** pElements; //pointer to list elements
    void (*deleteArrayList)();
    void (*add)();
    void (*remove)();
    void (*set)();
    void* (*get)();
    int (*indexOf)();
    int (*len)();
    void (*clear)();
    void (*push)();
    void* (*pop)();
    int (*contains)();
    int (*isEmpty)();
    //Extras
    int (* containsAll)();
    struct ArrayList* (*clone)(); //trouble1
    struct ArrayList* (*subList)();//trouble2 
} ArrayList;
```

As you can see, two elements type `int`, and pointers to functions, but I only have troubles with the last two. I have an initializator as follows:

```
ArrayList* al_newArrayList(void) { 
    ArrayList* list;
    list = (ArrayList *) malloc (sizeof(ArrayList));
    list->size = 0;
    list->pElements = malloc(sizeof(void *) * 10);
    list->reservedSize = 10;
    list->add = al_add;
    list->deleteArrayList = al_deleteArrayList;
    list->remove = al_remove;
    list->set = al_set;
    list->get = al_get;
    list->indexOf = al_indexOf;
    list->len = al_len;
    list->clear = al_clear;
    list->push = al_push;
    list->pop = al_pop;
    list->contains = al_contains;
    list->isEmpty = al_isEmpty;
    list->containsAll = al_containsAll;
    list->clone = al_clone;//trouble1
    list->subList = al_subList;//trouble2
    return list;
}
```

The program works but have a runtime error, and I have warnings about wrong referencing at:

```
list->clone = al_clone;//trouble1
list->subList = al_subList;//trouble2
```

Even those functions works but the program is closed. Do you have any idea? Wrong syntax?

Comment: Adding some formatting will help you make your code more readable.

Comment: you have to post `al_subList` and `al_clone` functions, i hope you are not returning a pointer to structs declared locally (from the stack).

Comment: Are you aware you almost completely inhibit automatic type-checking by the compiler? This is quite a bad idea.

Comment: @milevyo nope, i dont

Comment: You should strongly consider using prototype declarations for the function pointer members of your `ArrayList` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    int reservedSize; // reserved size
    int size; // Size of list
    // ...
    struct ArrayList* (*clone)(); //trouble1
    struct ArrayList* (*subList)();//trouble2 
} ArrayList;
```

By the time the compiler gets to the "trouble" lines there is no type named `struct ArrayList`.

There is a struct type with no tagname being defined.

At the end of that definition, there will be a type named `ArrayList` (a struct type with no tagname) defined.

Solution:

define the type `struct ArrayList`

```
typedef struct ArrayList {             // define type with tagname
    int reservedSize; // reserved size
    int size; // Size of list
    // ...
    struct ArrayList* (*clone)(); //trouble1
    struct ArrayList* (*subList)();//trouble2 
} ArrayList;
```

Comment: Won't the `struct ArrayList` and `... } ArrayList;` lines give a compiler error saying  something like `redefining the name ArrayList`?

Comment: i really appreciate your help, it fixed thanks!! now it works perflectly. This proyect is prerrequisite for my final exam.

Comment: @Killa, you have to accept the answer, or at least up vote for him (if possible)

Comment: @Jupiter: No, `typedef`s and `struct`s use two different name spaces.

Comment: There is no redifinition. The identifier `ArrayList` lives in global scope, the identifier `struct ArrayList` lives in struct scope. These two scopes do not clash in C.

Comment: @Jupiter maybe in C++ but this is C, so `struct ArrayList` is different to `ArrayList`. (I mean different syntactically. Semantically, the types are identical in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

All thanks goes to @pmg who points me.

```
typedef struct ArrayList ArrayList;
struct ArrayList{
    int reservedSize; // reserved size
    int size; // Size of list
    void ** pElements; //pointer to list elements
    void (*deleteArrayList)();
    void (*add)();
    void (*remove)();
    void (*set)();
    void* (*get)();
    int (*indexOf)();
    int (*len)();
    void (*clear)();
    void (*push)();
    void* (*pop)();
    int (*contains)();
    int (*isEmpty)();
    //Extras
    int (* containsAll)();
    struct ArrayList* (*clone)(); //trouble1
    struct ArrayList* (*subList)();//trouble2 
};
```

Comment: @sth i voted up for him. and i am inviting people to vote up for him, that what `All thanks goes to` means

Comment: Yeah I kind of confused you with the asker of the question